# d3 in Vue application - How to apply zooming on a map

Tags: vue.js, d3.js, vuejs2

I want to implement this example as a Vue.js application:

https://blockbuilder.org/adkdev/fe15a54ad3748c72e059475e3f43d462

My approach would be something like this:

```
<template>
    <svg>
       <path
        v-for="(item, index) in features"
        :key="index"
        :stroke-width="countyBorderWidth"
        :class="{ active: isActive(index) }"
        :d="geoPath(item)"
        v-on:click="clickedCountry(index, item.id)"
      >
    </svg>
</template>
<script>
 projection() {
      const p = d3.geoNaturalEarth1();
      p.fitSize([this.width, this.height], this.features);
      return p;
    },
 geoPath() {
   return d3.geoPath().projection(this.projection);
 },
 zoom(item) {
    // TODO
 }
</script>
```

And then have the `zoom()` method do the zooming.

My problem is the zoom part, since in the example it is called on `g`:

```
// Zoom
 g.transition()
.duration(750)
.attr('transform', 'translate(' + width / 2 + ',' + height / 2 + ')scale(' + k + ')translate(' + -x + ',' + -y + ')');
```

How would you convert this example to a Vue application, specifically, how would you implement the zooming of the map?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You identified the problem well. The zoom is made on the **group** (`g`).

Since you don't have `<g>` you can add it like this:

```
<template>
  <svg>
    <g>
      <path
        v-for="(item, index) in features"
        :key="index"
        :stroke-width="countyBorderWidth"
        :class="{ active: isActive(index) }"
        :d="geoPath(item)"
        v-on:click="clickedCountry(index, item.id)"
      >
    </g>
  </svg>
</template>
```

and then select it in the method `zoom`:

```
zoom(item) {
    d3.select('g').transition()
      .duration(750)
      .attr('transform', 'translate(' + width / 2 + ',' + height / 2 + ')scale(' + k + ')translate(' + -x + ',' + -y + ')');
```

If you want to leave `<g>` out and continue with what you have, select the `<svg>` directly:

```
zoom(item) {
    d3.select('svg').transition()
      .duration(750)
      .attr('transform', 'translate(' + width / 2 + ',' + height / 2 + ')scale(' + k + ')translate(' + -x + ',' + -y + ')');

}
```

Alternatively you could do everything in the `<script>` part of your component and leave only `<svg>` in the `<template>` part:

```
<template>
  <svg></svg>
</template>
```

Then you specify the styling and the attributes as well as manage the events like `click` with D3.js. That would be the code from the linked example. You'll need to reorganise it and group it into few methods.